# Function to calculate score of questionnaire (different time, factor variables)

Tags: r

I used to code with Stata and now I have to learn R which gives me some headache. I will try to ask good questions and would not mind, if you tell me how to improve them.

In the image / table you can see the data set and calculations (without function). The result is to_p_scale_s1_na
[image: Table with data and calculated score]

This is what I did to calculate the score (including descriptions and to create the data set):

```
# Create Data
t0_item1 <- c(0,1,0,1,NA,NA)
t0_item1 <- factor(t0_item1,    labels = c("yes", "no"))
t0_item2 <- c(1,1,0,1,0,1)
t0_item2 <- factor(t0_item2,    labels = c("yes", "no"))
t0_item3 <- c(1,0,1,1,0,NA)
t0_item3 <- factor(t0_item3,    labels = c("yes", "no"))
t0_item4 <- c(0,0,1,1,1,1)
t0_item4 <- factor(t0_item4,    labels = c("yes", "no"))
t1_item1 <- c(1,1,0,1,NA,0)
t1_item1 <- factor(t1_item1,    labels = c("yes", "no"))
t1_item2 <- c(1,0,0,1,NA,1)
t1_item2 <- factor(t1_item2,    labels = c("yes", "no"))
t1_item3 <- c(1,0,0,1,NA,1)
t1_item3 <- factor(t1_item3,    labels = c("yes", "no"))
t1_item4 <- c(0,0,0,1,NA,1)
t1_item4 <- factor(t1_item4,    labels = c("yes", "no"))
data_t0 <- data.frame(t0_item1, t0_item2, t0_item3, t0_item4)
data_t1 <- data.frame(t1_item1, t1_item2, t1_item3, t1_item4)
rm(t0_item1, t0_item2, t0_item3, t0_item4, t1_item1, t1_item2, t1_item3, t1_item4)

head(data_t0)

#Code without function

#Data / different datasets can be easily aranged in the same order. 
#But what comes now needs to be done many times for different points in time
#different scales with different possibilities to answere...
#In the excample:
#item 1 and 2 add 1 to total points of indicator, if answere is yes 
#item 3 and 4 add 1 to total points of indicator, if answere is no
#I had trouble using the data as they are coded as factors and with handling the NAs
# Probably there are better ways to this.

#Data will be ordered in dataframes accordingly to use rowSums command.

attach(data_t0)
# Skala 1 (all Variables)
list_scale_1_t0 <- data.frame(t0_item1, t0_item2, t0_item3, t0_item4)
# scale a adds 1 to total score if yes
list_scale_1a_t0 <- data.frame(t0_item1, t0_item2)
# scale b adds 1 if  no
list_scale_1b_t0 <- data.frame(t0_item3, t0_item4)
detach(data_t0)

# Count NAs and available data
# NAs
list_scale_1_t0$na <- rowSums(is.na(list_scale_1_t0))
# available data
list_scale_1_t0$all <- 4 - list_scale_1_t0$na

# 3. Now rowSums is used to count for  yes and now respectively
# Scale
# 1 = yes (2 Items)
list_scale_1_t0$t0_p_scale_s1a <- rowSums(list_scale_1a_t0 == "yes", na.rm=T)
summary(list_scale_1_t0$t0_p_scale_s1a)
# 1 = no (2 Items)
list_scale_1_t0$t0_p_scale_s1b <- rowSums(list_scale_1b_t0 == "no", na.rm=T)
summary(list_scale_1_t0$t0_p_scale_s1b)
# sum both parts of the total indicator
list_scale_1_t0$t0_p_scale_s1 <- list_scale_1_t0$t0_p_scale_s1a + list_scale_1_t0$t0_p_scale_s1b
summary(list_scale_1_t0$t0_p_scale_s1)

# In order to not count an NA as 0 points:
list_scale_1_t0$t0_p_scale_s1_na <- list_scale_1_t0$t0_p_scale_s1 / list_scale_1_t0$all * 4

# Exclude data with more then one NA
# Skala 1: 4 Items ->  min. 3 available / max. 1 NAs (25%)
list_scale_1_t0$t0_p_scale_s1_na[list_scale_1_t0$na>1] <- NA
summary(list_scale_1_t0$t0_p_scale_s1_na)

#The result is as I want it to be!
```

I tried various things with functions and some things did worked. I would appreciate help to optimize the above?

```
#Now this needs to be done multiple times and I am supposed to build a function to do it:
#Function is supposed to first adress data_t0 and then address data_t1 and 
#do the calculations and add the result to data_t0 and data_t1

fkt.scale1 <- function(df_source, df_s1, df_s1a, df_s1b) {
  # Take data for total indicator from source
  df_s1 <- data.frame(df_source$item_1, df_source$item_2, df_source$item_3, df_source$item_4)
  # count NAs and available data
  df_s1$na <- rowSums(is.na(df_s1))
  df_s1$all <- 4 - df_s1$na
  # df_s1a create scale a (adds 1 if yes)
  df_s1a <- data.frame(df_s1$item_1, df_s1$item_2)
  # df_s1b create scale b (adds 1 if no)
  df_s1b <- data.frame(df_s1$item_3, df_s1$item_4)
  #  count yes / no and add to index as seperate variables
  df_s1$t0_p_scale_s1a <- rowSums(df_s1a == "yes", na.rm=T)
  df_s1$t0_p_scale_s1b <- rowSums(df_s1b == "no", na.rm=T)
  # Sum
  df_s1$t0_p_scale_s1 <- df_s1$t0_p_scale_s1a + df_s1$t0_p_scale_s1b
  df_source
  #I kept trying different things and it would be too confusing to confusing to add more.
}

data_t0 <- fkt.scale1(data_t0, df_s1, df_s1a, df_s1b)
data_t1 <- fkt.scale1(data_t1, df_s1, df_s1a, df_s1b)

#Advice how to handle this better highly appreciated :)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to optimize?

Comment: I want to create a funciton (loop?) which takes repeatedly data in the above form for different points in time from different tables (t0, t1, t2...) make the transformation (calculate score and add to original table) and add the data to the original table.

Comment: Can you water down your example? It seems somewhat verbose right now.

Comment: Sorry when I was not clear and for late response. I would like to make the above into a function. Idea is you have (see table) item 1-4 and calculate t0_p_scale_s1_na (which is a score where item 1 and 2 add one, if "yes" and item 3 and  4 add one, if "no". Data = NA if more then 1 missing). The function is supposed to do this for different times (t0 and t1). But I am not entirely sure, if a function is the best option to do this? You mean to create a simpler excample?